# AWS SAM Unable to access Maven package published on Github Package

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I have successfully published a Maven Package to Github Packages.

Looks like this on the Github packages page:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.conectar.meetings</groupId>
  <artifactId>github-meetings-serverless-lib</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I try to use this package in my AWS SAM application, I get an error trying to install it.

It fails on the build step of my SAM app even though I supply the GITHUB_TOKEN as an env var:

```
- name: SAM Build for Prod Environment
        run: |
          cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
          sam build --parameter-overrides EnvStage=prod TableName=${{ secrets.PROD_DB_TABLENAME }} && sam package --s3-bucket ${{ secrets.PROD_AWS_DEPLOY_BUCKET }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
```

Here's the build error:

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/software/amazon/ion/ion-java/1.0.2/ion-java-1.0.2.jar (565 kB at 333 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.12/httpclient-4.5.12.jar (778 kB at 458 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.056 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-12T12:55:57Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error:  Failed to execute goal on project CreateMeeting: Could not resolve dependencies for project CreateMeeting:CreateMeeting:jar:1.0: Could not find artifact com.conectar.meetings:github-meetings-serverless-lib:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
Error:  
Error:  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Why can't it find the artifact?
I expect it to use the GITHUB_TOKEN to authenticate the build, but it seems to not be using that.
The package is published in the same repo where Github action is also running.

How do I make AWS SAM know about this Github Package?

Comment: where your build is running ? codebuild or github ? bitbucket?

Comment: the build is running on Github Actions

Comment: [The token's permissions are limited to the repository that contains your workflow.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow#about-the-github_token-secret)  is. your package in the same repo as where you build runs? asking because this information not included in the OP

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and yes the package is in the same repo where the build runs.